# How git works when the file permission mode is changed

Tags: linux, git

I changed the file mode by command `chmod +111 file.txt` then I checked GIT status and it showed:

> On branch master
>   Changes not staged for commit:
>     (use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
>     (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)

```
    modified:   file.txt
```

> no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Then I committed the changes but after then it stopped taking file permission changes into account as even on changing permission level to `+777` it shows

> On branch master
>   nothing to commit, working tree clean

Why file permission is not being taken into account anymore?

Comment: Check this answer in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10516406/2291935)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Git tracks exactly one bit of permission: executable or not executable.

You don't say what you mean *precisely* by "it stopped taking file permission changes into account", but my best guess is that you didn't change the executable permission, and so from Git's point of view, there *was no change* to take into account.

Answer (score 7):

I suspect you've got git filemode set to false, and you want it true.

To show git filemode:

`git config --get --local core.filemode`

or

`git config --get --global core.filemode`

Values:

`true`: git tracks the executable bit for the file owner.

`false`: git does not track it.

Ref: https://medium.com/@tahteche/how-git-treats-changes-in-file-permissions-f71874ca239d